# coding rules in the linux kernel

Tags: source-code

A rumor states that some person perhaps named Arpan Mukherjee has contributed some coding rules inside Linux kernel. If you did met that person, please tell (e.g. by email to `basile@starynkevitch.net`)

Unfortunately, I did not found any document mentioning coding rules for the Linux kernel (I `grep`-ed the entire source tree of `linux-5.13.12`) and that name.

I also did not found coding rules under https://kernelnewbies.org/

I am interested in taking inspiration from existing coding rules (in written English) for defining some of them in the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project.

I glanced inside some files of the Linux kernel and was unable to guess any kind of coding rules. But found [these](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html) (without any name like Arpan)

The GTK project, and the [MISRA C](https://www.misra.org.uk/misra-c/) standards, are defining coding rules or guidelines ([here](https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/guidelines/programming/coding-style.html) for GTK).

Comment: I vote to close this question. It is off topic for this group, it should be rather in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why? StackOverflow requires some [mre] that is some piece of code. I am seeking for a set of English sentences, not a sequence of C statements.

Comment: I looked at [this page](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and failed to see much overlap with your question. Moreover, the topic of 'coding rules' appear to be [showing up more often in Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22coding+rules%22). That's why. But obviously my suggestion did not find a lot of support. That's also OK.

Comment: The much more common search phrase is "coding style": https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22coding+style%22+kernel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel's coding style is at [Documentation/process/coding-style.rst](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/process/coding-style.rst) in the official repo.

While that file dates from 2016, it is just a reformatting of the pre-existing [Documentation/CodingStyle](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/CodingStyle) which has existed since at least the late 1990s; I can't easily find the exact date it was first created because the Git history "only" goes back to the initial import into Git in 2006.

Comment: Have you met once Arpan Mukherjee?

Comment: Arpan as a first name and Mukherjee (or Mukerjee, Mookerjee, Mukerji, Mukherji, Mukhujje, Mookherjee, depending on the spelling of the region) as a last name are very very common names in India. I would assume it is not difficult to find one of the probably 10s of thousands with this name combination, but it will be hard to find the specific one you are searching for.